# makecert.exe missing in windows 7, how to get it and use it

Tags: windows-7, makecert

I am using Windows 7. I don't have the **makecert.exe**, which I came to know when I tried to run commands to generate certificates like

```
makecert -sk XYZ -n "CN=XYZ Company" testXYZ.cer
```

I get error :

```
'makecert' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Pls suggest how to resolve this issue. Do i need to install the  Windows SDK again.

Regards,
Pravin.

Answer (score 38):

makecert.exe comes with both Visual Studio and the Windows SDK. Therefore just use either the Visual Studio Command Prompt or the Windows SDK command prompt and it will work straight out of the box as it will be included in the command prompt path.

`makecert` is included in the ".NET Development > Tools" bucket.

**This selected bucket includes** the **makecert** utility (at least in SDK v7.1).
[image: This selected bucket includes the makecert utility (SDK v7.1).]

Comment: If you only need makecert: Install the version of windows SDK for your computer. During installation, untick everything except .net tools.

Comment: ...and if you just selected the default install location, `makecert.exe` (and `pvk2pfx.exe`) will be inside `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin`

Answer (score 13):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64

OR

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86

Comment: On Windows 7, the default install directory is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin

Answer (score 11):

You can find a version of makecert here : http://www.inventec.ch/chdh/notes/makecert_5_131_3790_0.zip. Also instructions on how to use it here : http://www.inventec.ch/chdh/notes/14.htm

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/4d50ce341be70511e9a871dd347b3f5793ea97787cdfc92045c0bcc8aae6e298/detection

Answer (score 9):

Have you read this link: [MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It sends you to [Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx) from where you can download the SDK including makecert

Comment: OP might have found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the top Google result for "makecert" but lacks the link to the SDK.  +1 MS for documentation consistency.

Answer (score 4):

I know its too late to reply, however it might help other looking out for this executable.

if you have installed VS 2005, you will find it under

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\Bin

if you have installed VS 2008, you will find it under

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools

go to this location on command prompt and then run you "makecert" command with arguments.

Answer (score 4):

[`MakeCert.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968) is now deprecated. You should use PowerShell's [`New-SelfSignedCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate) cmdlet to create a selfsigned certificate.

Comment: Is your question, how to install powershell on Windows 7, then maybe this will help https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/07/how-do-i-install-powershell-on-windows-7-and-other-questions/

Comment: As another question points out, [New-SelfSignedCertificate will not run on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43592526/1331011). So no, my question is not how to install Powershell on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it on microsoft sdks directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\makecert.exe

Answer (score 1):

My copy (with Visual Studio 2017 installed) was here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64\makecert.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem awhile back and thought I would share the link I found to download and install this tool.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84091

Please let me know if this works if you do get around to it, I realize this post is a little old.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 after installing Windows SDKs:

If you have ARM microprocessor: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\arm64

Intel microprocessor: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64

Add that folder to your PATH environment variable