# New-SelfSignedCertificate will not run on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

On a Windows 7 Professional system, it seems not possible to run New-SelfSignedCertificate. I could on a Windows 10 system.

Yes, the shell was started with "Run As Administrator."

```
PS C:\> new-selfsignedcertificate
new-selfsignedcertificate : The term 'new-selfsignedcertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-selfsignedcertificate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (new-selfsignedcertificate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

Comment: Correct. The `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet is part of the [PKIClient module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/pkiclient) that ships with Windows 10

Comment: It appears that for Windows 7, the developer must go to Microsoft to get `makecert.exe`.

Comment: Confirmed `New-SelfSignedCertificate` runs on Windows 8.1 Pro. We are using it to generate our self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, this isn't available in Windows 7.

However, if you're looking for something with a similar API and capability, then I have used & can recommend this from Microsoft Script Centre:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6

Comment: It sounds very good, but I am thinking to stick with the deprecated makecert for use on the deprecated Windows 7 systems.

Answer (score 2):

Have to install AzureRM module to use azure commands through powershell. You can use below command to do it.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber
```