# 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, subject-alternative-name

I'm trying to create a SAN ssl certificate using powershell but this error shows up (please click link below to see what I've typed in my powershell):

[image: Powershell error]

> The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function,script file or operable program.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

This is my powershell version:

[image: powershell version]

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running this on?

Comment: @OwainEsau hi I've added the version to my question.

Comment: Is this running on a Windows 10 PC?

Comment: Sorry a windows 7 PC

Comment: @OwainEsau yes windows 7

Comment: ok, well New-SelfSignedCertificate doesnt work on windows 7 ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592526/new-selfsignedcertificate-will-not-run-on-windows-7 )

Comment: @OwainEsau Thanks for your help

Comment: I have installed the latest version of powershell i.e version 5 on windows server 2008 r2 but still see the same error. Any suggestions on what to do? It runs perfectly fine on windows 2016 server.