# Unable to generate certificates for a device in group enrollements - azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am  following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-group-enrollments 
this article to create a group enrollment and add devices to that.  I have completed the first two steps i.e

- prepare the environment
- Create a device enrollment entry

While doing the **simulate the device** step. It is showing that
"{deviceName}-public.pem file and include this value as your Client Cert. Open your {deviceName}-all.pem file ".

[image]

I am not able to find the two .pem files. Where can I find these files and how to generate those files?

Can somebody please help me in solving this issue.

I am getting following error although I have set the path in System variable

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the creation of the enrollment entry step, have you created the device certificates (not the root or intermediate ones), mentioned in the step 4.c? If so, you already should have both the device public and private keys.

Comment: Yes I have created by following the step 4 in link " https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md " Is this is how we need to create device certificate?

Comment: in the step 4 there are the steps to create the device on IoT Hub, and also the device certificates. Either follow one of the two ways (using Bash or PowerShell) for IoT Leaf Device, depending on the tool you used to create root and intermediate. This one should give you device certificates using Bash script https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md#iot-leaf-device-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "[prepare the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-group-enrollments#prepare-the-environment)" part, there is a step 4:

> 4. Use the following [Certifcate Overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md) to create your test certificates.

you will create all the certificates you will need.

For device certificate created in this step:

[Step 4 - Create a new device](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/tools/CACertificates/CACertificateOverview.md#step-4---create-a-new-device)

> Where can I find these files and how to generate those files?

If you use PowerShell and for example, use "x509devicetogroup" as the device name in the following command:

```
New-CACertsDevice x509devicetogroup
```

You will get the following certificates in your working folder:

[image]

Here x509devicetogroup-public.pem and x509devicetogroup-all.pem files are what you need.

**Update:**

If you get the following error when using PowerShell to create certificates:

```
openssl : The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\Sample\azure-iot-sdk-c\tools\CACertificates\ca-certs.ps1:367 char:5
+     openssl pkcs12 -in $newDevicePfxFileName -out $newDevicePemAllFil ...
+     ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (openssl:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Add a variable named "OPENSSL_CONF" to system environment variables:

[image]

Add a new system path variable points to OPENSSL bin directory like this:

[image]

Comment: I have tried using PowerShell but I got an error saying OpenSSL is unavailable.When I checked the path "$env:OPENSSL_CONF" It's showing
"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.cnf". How do you set the path? And Is there anything that I need to do to run openssl in windows?

Comment: @arun Check the system environment variables and add a variable named "OPENSSL_CONF" if it doesn't exist. For more detailed info please check my updated answer. Feel free let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Han I did the steps that you have suggested me to do but still getting the OpenSSL error. I have updated my question with screenshots. Please have a look into it and guide me to the solution

Comment: @arun Add openssl bin directory to the system path variables. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added OpenSSL bin to the system path and am able to complete the step 1 successfully but when I am executing the step2 command i.e "New-CACertsCertChain ecc" .I am getting following error

"New-CACertsCertChain : The term 'New-SelfSignedCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again."

Comment: @arun Run `. .\ca-certs.ps1` before you execute any other functions. This is called dot-sourcing and brings the functions of the script into PowerShell's global namespace.

Comment: I did that I ran " . .\ca-certs.ps1".  It executed successfully with two warnings and then I ran "Test-CACertsPrerequisites" which I got success and then I executed "New-CACertsCertChain ecc" command to generate a certificate and I am getting following output "Beginning to install certificate chain to your LocalMachine\My store
Testing if any test certificates have already been installed...
  Ok.WARNING: Generating certificate CN=Azure IoT CA TestOnly Root CA which is for prototyping, NOT PRODUCTION.." and then followed by the error that I stated in the previous comment

Comment: @arun I found it seems New-SelfSignedCertificate only supported by Windows 8.1 or later. [Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592526/new-selfsignedcertificate-will-not-run-on-windows-7). So just to confirm that what's your version of Windows desktop?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: So that's the reason for the error..thank you for the clarification. I have executed bash scripts and files got generated but I am not able to find out which file is the public key and which file is the private key because no file is ending with " .all.pem.file"

Comment: @arun The file, for example, like **new-device.key.pem** that contains the device's private key. The file, for example, like **new-device-full-chain.cert.pem** contains  the public key. Private key starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and pubic key starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. The PowerShell and Bash scripts are functionally equivalent and only result in different file names.

Comment: Thanks for the help.My new-device.key.pem starts with " ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---" . Are you able to add the device to the group by adding bash generated public and private key? Becasue i am getting handshake exception

Comment: @arun I can't test bash. Can you show detailed exception information? Which line causes the exception?

Comment: Han I managed to run the PowerShell scripts in windows 8 and able to generate public and private files. But when I executed the program . I am getting the following error "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.exceptions.ProvisioningDeviceHubException: {"errorCode":400004,"trackingId":"2365b551-cd83-4116-a161-4
dd915213c9a","message":"Invalid RegistrationId","timestampUtc":"2018-08-06T14:43:18.4778556Z"} 
". Could you pleas tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: @arkay In the case of X.509-based attestation, the registration ID is provided as the subject name of the certificate. And the registration ID must be alphanumeric, lowercase, and may contain hyphens. That is the device name in this command:`New-CACertsDevice mydevice`. You can have a check yours.

Comment: Thanks Rita han for the help.I am able to solve the issue by changing the device name. You are the best :)

Comment: @arkay Glad to help :)